# Knockout JS - Multidimensional observableArrays and displaying sub-array data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm close to going nuts about this now and figured it'd be simple, however, there must be something I'm missing...

I've got a multidimensional array in a ko.observableArray, in which is so:

Site -> Company -> Job

For my data binds, `data-bind="text: Site().Name"` is fine, as you would expect. However, I can't access the sub-arrays by `data-bind="text: Site().Company().Name"` or `data-bind="text: Site().Company.Name"`.

Has anyone else had the same issue, or is there something I'm doing drastically wrong? The objects are 100% being loaded into the array properly as I can see them in the console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly and a `Site` contains an observableArray of `Company` objects and each `Company` object contains an observableArray of `Job` objects, then your approach will not work.

`data-bind="text: Site().Company().Name"` is trying to get the `Name` property of an observableArray that happens to contain `Company` objects. You could however write `data-bind="text: Site().Company()[0].Name"` to get the name of the first `Company`.

A more common approach would be to iterate through the items. Something like:

```
<!-- ko with: Site -->
Site name is <span data-bind="text: Name"/>
<ul>
  <!-- ko foreach: Company -->
    <li>Company name is <span data-bind="text: Name"/>
      <!-- ko foreach: Job -->
        <li>Job name is <span data-bind="text: Name"/>
        </li>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
```

See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html for more details.

Hope this is what you are looking for and apologies if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm going to go down the route of the foreach bindings (even if there's only 1 element in my arrays) as it just seems to make life easier.